# Insert statement at row where MyCol is x

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have 2 columns MyCol and NewCol. MyCol has already been populated, and may have duplicates (it's not the primary key). I need to insert a value y into NewCol at all rows where MyCol = x. I'm stuck here and not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an update statement

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET NewCol = Y
WHERE MyCol = x
```

Why exactly could you not find this in ANY introduction to SQL - book, article, reference, team-mate etc?

Comment: Will this do this operation WHEREVER MyCol = x?

Comment: I was under the impression it was first instance

Comment: @Angus - SQL works with sets not items.  It will change all of them.  If you want to change one item then you need to explain how to know which item that is.